# Custom path resolving static resources Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am working on Spring Boot application. The general problem is the following: I've created REST API, a few controllers. However, I also have some static HTML files, located in "resources/static".

What I want to achieve, is to configure Spring resolvers so that I could access static content without appending ".html". On practise, I expect to access static HTML by path "ip:port/htmlPage" instead of "ip:port/htmlPage.html"

However, I don't want to create methods like this one:

```
@Controller
public class ViewMaster {
@RequestMapping("/home")
public String home() {
    return "home";
}
```

So, properties like

```
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.html
```

not working for me. Any possibilities to avoid creation per page endpoint in a controller?

Comment: So how are planning to map the requests to the controllers?

Comment: @mirmdasif, for example: serve requests after "static" (anything other) by static resources view resolver, otherwise - search for REST endpoints

Answer (score 2):

After reading your question i have tried a lot but unable to serve html from static folder without extention. What works for me is to create an `@RequestMapping` like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/static/{htmlName}")
String getStaticHtml(@PathVariable String htmlName){
    return htmlName;
}
```

And moved html files to `templates` folder. So there is no need to create different end points to access html pages, just pass the name of html without extention and this will do the trick